# Can streptavidin be conjugated with EDC-activated carboxylates?

Tags: biochemistry, fluorescent-microscopy

Recently I conducted an experiment to conjugate amine-modified oligonucleotides with hydrogel particles having carboxyl groups. However, the fluorescence (from hybridized FAM-DNA) only appears on a small area of the particle and its shape is this ill-defined, like in the image below. 
[image: Particle+FAM-DNA]

My advisor said that "DNA is negative charge and carboxyl group also have negative charge so there is no possibility of conjugation, conjugation of streptavidin to particle, attaching biotinylated DNA and proceed with hybridization".

However, conjugation using NHS / EDC requires both an amine group and a carboxyl group. Does streptavidin have the requisite chemical groups to do such a conjugation? Streptavidin is Sigma Aldrich's 85878 (Streptavidin of Streptomyces avidinii, affinity purified, 10 mM potassium phosphate, lyophilized product of ≧ 13 U / mg protein).

PS: Please tell me if there is a secret to make it conjugate evenly on the surface.

PPS: We use 5 μM anime modified oligonucleotide and 100 nM FAM-DNA.

Comment: I really don't get why this question had a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

The EDC-activated carboxylate is actually positively charged, though I cannot speak to the density of carboxylates in your hydrogel or the extent of activation with your protocol. Subsequent NHS activation generates a negatively charged adduct. If charge repulsion is an issue during coupling, you can try experimenting with salt concentration or adjusting pH around streptavidin’s isoelectric point (but keep in mind that the reactions themselves also have a pH optimum).

Streptavidin has plenty of primary amines (lysine and N-terminus) to react with EDC- or EDC/NHS-activated carboxylates, and is routinely conjugated to carboxylate functionalized resins. As streptavidin also has carboxylate groups, it may be desirable activate the resin first and then conjugate streptavidin to avoid unwanted side-reactions.

[You can read about the EDC/NHS reaction mechanism here (ThermoFisher).](https://www.thermofisher.com/us/en/home/life-science/protein-biology/protein-biology-learning-center/protein-biology-resource-library/pierce-protein-methods/carbodiimide-crosslinker-chemistry.html#2)

[image]